# Sequelize v7 alpha @ decorators not working

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

While testing sequelize v7 (alpha) I came across several errors while using simple examples straight from their documentation. For example, straight from the [documentation](https://sequelize.org/docs/v7/models/defining-models/)

```
import { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model, InferAttributes, InferCreationAttributes, CreationOptional } from '@sequelize/core';
import { Attribute, PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, NotNull } from '@sequelize/core/decorators-legacy';

const sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite::memory:');

export class User extends Model<InferAttributes<User>, InferCreationAttributes<User>> {
  @Attribute(DataTypes.INTEGER)
  @PrimaryKey
  @AutoIncrement
  declare id: CreationOptional<number>;

  @Attribute(DataTypes.STRING)
  @NotNull
  declare firstName: string;

  @Attribute(DataTypes.STRING)
  declare lastName: string | null;
}
```

Results in import error `Cannot find module '@sequelize/core/decorators-legacy' or its corresponding type declarations.`

Also, `Decorators are not valid here.` where we declare the `@Attribute` decorators error as well.

Following along with their documentation is proving to be difficult. Has anyone managed to implement sequelize v7 alpha? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

To resolve `Cannot find module '@sequelize/core/decorators-legacy' or its corresponding type declarations`. You must set the **module** and **moduleResolution** options to **NodeNext**.

To resolve `Decorators are not valid here.` You must set the **experimentalDecorators** option to **true**.

See an example

tsconfig.json

```json
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "experimentalDecorators": true
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According this thread [Cannot import decorators-legacy in V7](https://github.com/sequelize/website/issues/552) you need change **moduleResolution** property in your *tsconfig.json* to **node16** or **nodenext** value.

In my case I have a *tsconfig.json* and a *tsconfig.serve.json* I change both.

Note that after update **moduleResolution** you also need update de **module** property to the same value

See an example

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "strict": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false
    ...
}
```

Comment: That solved the import issue, but I'm still getting "TS1206: Decorators are not valid here.". Did you manage to solve it, @bricewa?